# How to create a Mongodb index in Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo)?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

How can I use the Robo 3T GUI to create a simple index for one of the fields in a collection?

When I click on my collection, right click on the indexes folder and choose "add Index..." I see the next screen, what should I enter in the fields (mainly in the "Keys" field)?

[image: Robo 3T Index Properties screenShot]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research and trial and error I found this is similar to the cli function  `db.collection.createIndex(keys, options)`

About the Keys field:
From the MongoDB documentation -

> A document that contains the field and value pairs where the field is
>   the index key and the value describes the type of index for that
>   field. For an ascending index on a field, specify a value of 1; for
>   descending index, specify a value of -1

Let's say our field to index name is "accountNumber",
you can enter this to the "Keys" black box pictured above:

```
{
      "accountNumber" : 1
}
```

For the Name just enter something meaningfull like accountNumberIndex

*The "Unique" checkbox will only work if there aren't already duplicate entries

*Also the Drop Duplicates is deprecated in Mongo version 3

Comment: I'm using RoboMongo (1.0) and I could create an index using the UI or the `createIndex` function.  If, however, I tried to use the UI and selected the checkbox **Unique** the index was not created (no error but not created).

Comment: Just trying to create a simple index on Robo3T, I get a pop up modal dialog with message "Please check json text".